# 'checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)' in 'androidx.core.content.ContextCompat' cannot be applied to

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i new to android, I am trying to make runtime permissions.but i got the erro

'checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)' in 'androidx.core.content.ContextCompat' cannot be applied to '(com.example.p2pwifichatapplication.WiFiDerectBroadcastReceiver, java.lang.String)'
i got this erro in line

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
```

this is my Activity code

```
public class WiFiDerectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private WifiP2pManager mManager;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
private MainActivity mActivity;


public WiFiDerectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager mManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel, MainActivity mActivity) {
    this.mManager = mManager;
    this.mChannel = mChannel;
    this.mActivity = mActivity;


}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "wifi is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "wifi is OOF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        if (mManager != null) {


            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, mActivity.peerListListener);
        }

    }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){

    }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){

    }

}
```

}

This is my build gradle file code

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 30

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.p2pwifichatapplication"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

Please any one can help me, please
what is this problem. how to solw this.?

Comment: you should not pass <this> to ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission() as first argument, because <this> is your broadcast receiver. Pass your mActivity or context